# Can I get PDO to throw an exception if the database is not found?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, xampp

I know that PDO will create a new database is it does not find the database referenced in the database path.

What if I want an error if it can't find the database I (think) I'm referencing?

I am using PDO, PHP, SQLITE and XAMPP.

I have 30+years programming exp but none on anything written after 1980. This is my first go at PHP.

Comment: As sqlite database is a simple file you can always check that manually like `if (!is_file($path)) throw new Exception("Database file not found");`

Comment: 30 years of experience like really?

Comment: So now you're 70 or 80 yo?

Comment: What I mean is... I have no experience of any programming language which was created after 1980.  My experience is of Assembler, Cobol, Fortran, AM250, Mantis, Abap, etc, All procedural languages.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a try catch statement as follow:

```
try {
  $pdo = new PDO(DRIVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  die("Your Message" . $e->getMessage());
}
```

even you can throw a new exception in catch block but I think it's not necessary because **PDOException** handles exceptions for you.